# Why is len(<a list object>) so slow?

Tags: python, ipython, timing

I'm running the following code in an `ipython` session:

```
# This call is slow, but that is expected. (It loads 3 GB of data.)
In [3]: arc, arc_sub, upls, go = foo_mod.ready_set()

# This call is also slow, as `upls` is huge.
In [4]: upls = list(upls)

# This call is slow in meatspace, but `%timeit` doesn't notice!
In [5]: %timeit -n1 -r1 len(upls)
1 loops, best of 1: 954 ns per loop
```

`%timeit` is straight-up lying here. With or without the `%timeit`, the command takes upwards of 10s to actually run. Only the first time, however; subsequent calls to `len` are quick.

Even `time.time()` sings a similar tune:

```
In [5]: import time

In [6]: s = time.time(); len_ = len(upls); e = time.time()

In [7]: e - s
Out[7]: 7.104873657226562e-05
```

But it took *seconds* in the real world for `In [6]` to actually complete. I just don't seem to be able to capture where the actual time is being spent!

There's nothing terribly unusual about the list, aside from it's huge: it's a real `list`; it holds ~¼ billion `bson.ObjectId` objects. (Prior to the `list()` call, it's a `set` object; *that* call is also slow, but that makes sense; `list(<set instance>)` is O(*n*), and my set is huge.)

**Edit re GC**

If I run `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_STATS)` just prior to `ready_set`, which itself is a slow call, I see tons of GC cycles. This is expected. gen3 grows:

```
gc: objects in each generation: 702 701 3289802
gc: done, 0.0000s elapsed.
gc: collecting generation 0...
gc: objects in each generation: 702 1402 3289802
gc: done, 0.0000s elapsed.
gc: collecting generation 0...
gc: objects in each generation: 702 2103 3289802
```

Unfortunately the console outputs make this runtime of this impossibly slow. If I instead delay the `gc.set_debug` call until just after `ready_set`, I don't see *any* GC cycles, but `gc.get_count()` claims the generations are tiny:

```
In [6]: gc.get_count()
Out[6]: (43, 1, 193)

In [7]: len(upls)
Out[7]: 125636395
```

(but why/how is `get_count` less objects than what's in the list?; they're definitely all unique, since they just went through a `set`…) The fact that involving `gc` in the code makes `len` speedy leads me to believe I'm paused for a collect-the-world.

(Versions, just in case:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
IPython 3.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

)

Comment: That's bizarre. Does the same thing happen in the regular interactive interpreter?

Comment: lists know their size. once it's in a list, len(thelist) is O(1)

Comment: @ChadS. For lists to know their size they have to calculate it at some point. I think that caching happens at first call to `len()`.

Comment: No. they just have to keep track of when items are inserted and removed. It doesn't calculate it when you call len.

Comment: @ChadS. That would be insanely inefficient. And a huge waste if you never call `len()`.

Comment: No it wouldn't, and knowing the len() of the list is needed for nearly ANY list operation.

Comment: @ChadS. Dude, it would. I know that people nowadays think that simple addition costs nothing but it does if you modify list all the time. Plus for what other operation needs it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102530/discussion-between-chad-s-and-freakish).

Comment: At this point, I've read the source code for Python 2.7. `list` knows its size intrinsically. The implementation of `len` for `list` is very simple. :-/ Unfortunately, it doesn't match the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: Do you happen to be running in an IDE like Spyder?

Answer (score 4):

I will summarize the comments to your question to the answer.

As everyone said (and you pointed it out), Python's `list` object knows its size and it [returns just the stored number](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c):

```
static Py_ssize_t
list_length(PyListObject *a)
{
    return Py_SIZE(a);
}
```

Where `Py_SIZE` [is defined](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/structures.html#c.Py_SIZE):

> Py_SIZE(o)
>
> This macro is used to access the ob_size member of a Python object. It expands to:
>   `(((PyVarObject*)(o))->ob_size)`

So I can conclude it should not do any calculations. The only suspected is the object you trying to convert to list. But if you swear it is really `list` without any fake objects simulating its method with some lazy calculations - it is not it.

So I assume that all `timeit` methods are really showing exact time spent to call `len` function.

And the only time-wasting process is.. **Garbage Collector**. At the end of your measurements it discovers that noone uses such large piece of data and starts releasing the memory. Sure, it takes some seconds.